# Slow n1ql query using object of objects structure

Tags: node.js, couchbase, sql++

In our couchbase db, we have a bucket with relatively large objects. These objects have other objects inside let's say people. This should be an array, however for some reason we had to create it as an object of objects, and this is how it looks like:

```
{
    "companyName": "company name",
    "companyid": "11111-GUID-11111",
    "people": {
        "22222-GUID-22222": {
            "peopleid": "22222-GUID-22222",
            "name": "name1"
        },
        "33333-GUID-33333": {
            "peopleid": "33333-GUID-33333",
            "name": "name2"
        },
        "44444-GUID-44444": {
            "peopleid": "44444-GUID-44444",
            "name": "name3"
        }
    }
}
```

It also have sub-objects with similar structure.

I can make queries on this document like this:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM companies c
WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) SATISFIES v.peopleid = "22222-GUID-22222" END 
LIMIT 100 
OFFSET 40000;
```

I have a bucket which has 50000 document like this.

The query above runs perfectly and gives me a correct response, but I have to wait about 25 seconds for the response.

Is there any possibility to create proper indexes on this structure? Or any solution which could speed up the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try creating array index as described https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html. You mentioned large objects check out the array index key size limit.

CREATE index ia1 ON companies (DISTINCT ARRAY v.peopleid FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(people) END);

As you use large offset you are discarding lot of documents. If you are using 4.6.2+ (because it can use Implicit covered array index described in above link)  You can get the META().id's of the LIMIT documents using covered query and fetch required documents like below.

```
SELECT c.* FROM
    (SELECT RAW META(c).id FROM companies c
       WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) 
                  SATISFIES v.peopleid = "22222-GUID-22222" END 
       LIMIT 100 OFFSET 40000) AS q 
 JOIN companies c ON KEYS q ;
```

Comment: you are the best. It works like a charm. Instead of 25s I'm getting responses in 2.5 sec.

Comment: If the query gets more complex and the people objects have, let's say, pets with similar structure (name and petid). Is there any possibility to create an index for the petid?

Comment: You can create another index and query on that CREATE index ia2 ON companies (DISTINCT ARRAY v.petid FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(pets) END);

Comment: I've tried this new index and the query is still slow.
Please note that the "pets" object is inside of "people" object, like this:
```"people": {
        "22222-GUID-22222": {
            "peopleid": "22222-GUID-22222",
            "name": "name1",
           "pets": {"33333-GUID-33333-pet": {
"petid": "33333-GUID-33333-pet",
"name": "petname"
}}
}```
When I try to make a query, where I want to query by petid as well, the query takes about 40 seconds (with 40k offset). Please note that the actual database is much more serious I'm only using people and pets, because it's confidential

Comment: Please checkout Example 4: Indexing the individual elements of nest arrays (C4,Q4)  because OBJECT_VALUES() produces array and follow similarly https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/indexing-arrays.html

Comment: Thank you @vsr, it works really well. The only problem is when I want to query by 'petid' and 'peopleid' in the same query. Then it slows down again.

Comment: Did you try two ANY clauses one for peopleid and another petid with both the indexes

Comment: Yes, however I just realised, that actually the problem is with a different part of the query. I've also attached the "companyid" and that was the slow part. Even if I created an index for that as well, like this: "CREATE INDEX `ia3` ON `companies`(`companyid`)". And used != operator for this, because I thought that using this operator (combined with AND) should speed up the query.

Comment: My query looks like this: ```SELECT c.* FROM
    (SELECT RAW META(c).id FROM companies c
        WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) 
                SATISFIES ANY pet in OBJECT_VALUES(v.pets) 
                    SATISFIES pet.petid = "1111111-111111-pet" END
                AND v.peopleid = "1111111-111111-people"
                END 
        AND c.companyid != "000045001-company"
        LIMIT 30 OFFSET 40000) AS q 
 JOIN companies r ON KEYS q;``` . It takes 40 secs to run. Without the company id it takes about 4 secs.

Comment: for companyid you can create composited index like CREATE index ia1 ON companies (DISTINCT ARRAY v.peopleid FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(people) END, companyid); and drop ia3. This is triky because you have two conditions on SATISFIES and index will not user cover(index doesn't have both info), The best way is just keep ia1 and SELECT c.*  FROM companies c WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) SATISFIES ANY pet in OBJECT_VALUES(v.pets) SATISFIES pet.petid = "1111111-111111-pet" END AND v.peopleid = "1111111-111111-people" END AND c.companyid != "000045001-company" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 40000;

Comment: Also try this. CREATE index ia4 ON companies (DISTINCT ARRAY (DISTINCT ARRAY [v.peopleid,p.petid] FOR p IN OBJECT_VALUES(v.pets) END) FOR v IN OBJECT_VALUES(people) END, companyid);
SELECT c.* FROM (SELECT RAW META(c).id FROM companies c WHERE ANY v IN OBJECT_VALUES(c.people) SATISFIES ANY p in OBJECT_VALUES(v.pets) SATISFIES [v.peopleid, p.petid] = ["1111111-111111-people","1111111-111111-pet"] END END AND c.companyid != "000045001-company" LIMIT 30 OFFSET 40000) AS q JOIN companies r ON KEYS q;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156996/discussion-between-sz-tech-and-vsr).